# Node.js serving HTML, execute command line and callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to use Node.js to serve up one HTML file and respond to a call on the same port.  When it serves the HTML page, I also want it to run a command locally to display the output of the command.  I can't seem to get the output.  It keeps erroring out.  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental but not sure what.  Here is the code snippet:

```
var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  }       
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.url.includes("callback")) {
      //do stuff
    } else {
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        res.write(html);  
        res.write("<BR><BR>NodeJS Server:"+hostname);        
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        var cmd = 'uname -a | awk \'\{print $2\}\'';
        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
          res.write("<BR><BR>uname output: "+ stdout);
        });
      res.end();
    }
  }).listen(80);
});
```

Here's the error I got:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:439:15)
    at /tmp/web-serve-one-port2.js:111:15
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what's the error ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry I should have included that.  I edited my question with the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `end()` before you do the last write, as `exec()` is asynchronous.

Here's basically what happening

```
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    res.write("<BR><BR>uname output: "+ stdout); // this happens last
});

res.end(); // this happens first
```

And you can write after the response has ended. Change your code to :

```
var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        if (req.url.includes("callback")) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            var cmd = 'uname -a | awk \'\{print $2\}\'';
            exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
                res.write(html);
                res.write("<BR><BR>NodeJS Server:" + hostname);
                res.write("<BR><BR>uname output: " + stdout);
                res.end();
            });

        }
    }).listen(80);
});
```

Comment: That's it!  As an aside, what if I want to run multiple commands? How will this change?

Comment: Then you'd nest one within the other, or use promises

Comment: I nested the other one and neither of them update.  Perhaps because when the page loads, the callback hasn't happened yet?

Answer (score 0):

With error output it will be easier to help. However it can be fast implemented with serve-static + express library.

Here is working sample:

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/WebContent")).listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
});
```

in WebContent folder put your index.html file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have added the error output.  For your sample, can you include executing a shell command, captures the output and display the output along side with the WebContent?